# Boot process involving 2 physical disks

Tags: boot

Based on my understanding, MBR partitioning scheme allows 4 primary partitions for each PHYSICAL MBR disk, and only one of those 4 partitions can be set active at any time.

Now if I have 2 physical disks, does that mean I can set one of the partition of the 2nd hard disk as active also? Is having 2 active partitions allowed, if they are on separate hard drives?

If yes, how does BIOS then determine which "active" partition to choose? And how is bootmgr relevant in this process?

Comment: Yes, there could be an active partition on each physical drive. *"how does BIOS then determine which "active" partition to choose?"* -- There's a boot drive/device list that orders the probe.  Use the BIOS to view or configure that list.

Comment: Mmm... yeah... there's those BIOS options.  Thanks @sawdust for a reminder of that.  Basically, such options re-order the disks (commonly), or maybe even disable the disks (hopefully less commonly).  Such behavior can affect which disk boots.  However, the BIOS then passes control to the code on the MBR of whichever disk boots.  The BIOS is completely unaware of the concept of a "partition", and doesn't do anything related to the "active partition" bit's setting.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the BIOS ignores the "active" partition bit.  What the BIOS does do is check for the magical signature (0x55AA) at the 511th and 512 bytes of the disk.  If that is found, the BIOS runs the code in the MBR.

The typical behavior of the MBR is to check the first disk's partition table and run the operating system that is in the first partition that is marked as active.  That means that the partition table's information for that partition has the "active" bit set to a value of 1.

However, whether that is actually what happens, or not, is up to the code in the MBR.  The BIOS's instructions have already passed control to the MBR's instructions at that point.  So the BIOS's boot instructions are already completed by this time.

It is possible to have the "active" bit set to 1 for multiple partitions.  With many FDISK programs, when you set one partition's "active" bit, it will de-select the other partitions' "active" bit.  That's quite common.  However, OpenBSD's fdisk is a known exception.  So, it is possible to have multiple active partitions on one disk.  The typical behavior, supported by some of the most common code installed into many MBRs (using code bundled with many popular operating systems), simply uses the first active partition on the first disk.

Booting an operating system on the second disk is completely unsupported by the code that is built into the MBRs created by many popular operating systems.  In theory, it can be done.  (I would think that Ranish Partition Manager's boot loader would support this, and maybe XFDisk's and GAG's.)  However, even if the code built into the MBR supports this, some operating systems (perhaps especially DOS) won't support this.  For no really compelling reason (like a technically impossible limitation), the reality is that a lot of older/traditional code just doesn't support that feature.